# 3-dimensional array of classes which will be searched

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list, stack

I'm new to C# and have read an introductory book to C# programming but am still unsure of the best approach to setting up a 3D array of a class. Here is a little background:

I need to keep track of instances of the class, called container, in stacks. There will be m by n stacks that will need to be tracked, hence the 3d array. Containers will be added and removed from the stacks. I will need to search through all the containers to find the containers that match some criteria. One of those container will be chosen; that container and all of the containers above it in that particular stack will need to be moved to another stack.

I figured using LINQ queries would be the best way to search over all of the containers which means I should use some kind of collection like a List to hold all of the containers. All of the collections I've seen seem to have only one indexer available which made me think I could just use a List and keep track of the 3D indexing on my own.

What is the correct approach to take?

Answer (score 0):

you can use/manage these well than the 3d array in C# code!

```
var d3Stack = new Stack<Stack<Stack<MyJob>>>();
var d3List = new List<List<List<MyJob>>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind with C# you can build your own Objects as containers.  This concept is generally referred to as a POCO, or Plain Old Class Object.  If you want to do collections that are more tailored to specific needs that you can update as needed it would be easy to create these objects.  If you want to keep it generic than use built ins.  Code should run in .NET 3.5 and up in Visual Studio.  I created it in LINQPad.  I would go this route if you want more specific functionality and keep in mind you can always change your objects later.

So let's create two container objects.  One is a parent and the other is a child of that parent for demonstration.  In a standard console app these could be outside of the 'Main' entry point.  Then I will create two methods to do some population to demonstrate the point of using the POCOs as containers.

```
public class JobListing
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
}

public List<Job> CreateJobs()
{
    return new List<Job>
    {
        new Job { Id = 1, Name = "First", Action = "Does It"},
        new Job { Id = 2, Name = "Second", Action = "Does It Again"},
        new Job { Id = 3, Name = "Third", Action = "Does It Yet Again"}
    };
}

public List<JobListing> CreateJobListings()
{
    return new List<JobListing>
    {
        new JobListing { Id = 1, Name = "First Area", Jobs = CreateJobs() },
        new JobListing { Id = 2, Name = "Second Area", Jobs = CreateJobs() }
    };
}

void Main()
{
    // I am just creating a variable that evaluates at runtime to hold my demo data.
    var jobslistings = CreateJobListings();

    // this is merely an example unboxing the data layer by layer
    jobslistings.ForEach(x => {
    //x => is a lambda statement and I am using Fluent Syntax off of a method that returns my containers.
    //x is now each object in my collection.  In this case it is a 'JobListing' object POCO I Made.
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", x.Id, x.Name));
        Console.WriteLine("\tJobs");
        x.Jobs.ForEach(y => {
        // y => is a lambda statement and I am now in an object of an object.
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\t\t{0} {1}", y.Id, y.Name));  
        });
    });

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Where Clause");
    Console.WriteLine();

    // now I am reusing my variable but with a 'predicate' lamba to do a where clause
    // this may narrow down my lookups later and I could use a similar example
    jobslistings.Where(predicate => predicate.Id == 1).ToList().ForEach(x => {
    //x => is a lambda statement and I am using Fluent Syntax off of a method that returns my containers.
    //x is now each object in my collection.  In this case it is a 'JobListing' object POCO I Made.
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", x.Id, x.Name));
        Console.WriteLine("\tJobs");
        x.Jobs.ForEach(y => {
        // y => is a lambda statement and I am now in an object of an object.
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\t\t{0} {1}", y.Id, y.Name));  
        });
    });
}
```